# UICollection view not redrawing gradient buttons

Tags: ios, xcode, reloaddata, uicollectionview, collectionview

I have a UICollectionView, which is populated with cells, and each cell has a gradient button (MKgradientbutton https://github.com/mikekatz/iOS-UI-Utils/tree/master/Classes/Button%20Widgets).  The view is 'changed' by pressing one of 5 other buttons, which in turn loads the data for the buttons into an array which provides the datasource for the uicollectionview.  One of the paramaters is the gradient button colour.  However on reloading the datasource and performing a [self.collectionView reloadData] the buttons title and the other paramaters will change but the colour will quite often change to completely the wrong one.  Repeatedly reloading the data will solve this problem - however, even more strangely, one press of the button seems to correct the colour of the button!  I have NSLogged the datasource array on the line before the reloadData takes place and all of the colours are correct.  I have pasted some code below - please bear with me as the app is still in the very early stages of development!

I really can't see any issues with the code - and I believe that the UICollectionView needs 'redrawn' but I assumed [self.CollectionView reloadData] would solve that!

Pulling data from sqlite db into and object then adding to array:

```
 Bird *bird = [[Bird alloc] init];

    bird.birdName = [results stringForColumn:@"name"];

    bird.buttonColour = [results stringForColumn:@"btncolour"];

[birds addObject:bird];
```

The array 'birds' being used to populate UICollectionView:

```
- (UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView2         cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    CollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView2     dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    Bird *bird = [birds objectAtIndex:(indexPath.row)];

    //Check button colour against index path of item
    NSLog(@"****INDEX PATH %i",indexPath.section*2 + indexPath.row);
    NSLog(@"****colour %@",bird.buttonColour);


    [cell.button setTitle:bird.birdName forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    [cell.button setTag:[birds indexOfObject:bird]];

    if ([bird.buttonColour isEqualToString:@"Green"]) {

 [cell.button setButtonColor:[UIColor greenColor]];

    }

    if ([bird.buttonColour isEqualToString:@"Orange"]) {

   [cell.button setButtonColor:[UIColor orangeColor]];
    }

    if ([bird.buttonColour isEqualToString:@"Red"]) {

      [cell.button setButtonColor:[UIColor redColor]];
    }

    if ([bird.buttonColour isEqualToString:@"Blue"]) {

   [cell.button setButtonColor:[UIColor blueColor]];
    }




    cell.button.titleLabel.numberOfLines = 0;
    cell.button.titleLabel.lineBreakMode = NSLineBreakByWordWrapping;
    cell.button.titleLabel.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;


      return cell; }
```

collectionViewCell.h (the gradient button is the only item in the cell):

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "MKGradientButton.h"

@interface CollectionViewCell : UICollectionViewCell


@property (nonatomic) IBOutlet MKGradientButton* button;


@end
```

Comment: I had no problem when I tried this code, but I created my birds array in the viewDidLoad, directly, rather than from a database download, so I think that may be the source of your problem. I think you need to update your post to show the whole method where you pull the data from the db and put it into birds.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to tell the button to redraw itself via `[cell.button setNeedsDisplay]`.